# Multi column compare to return most common value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 6 columns of strings and im looking for the most common string among all 6 columns.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Orange | Banana | Kiwi | Brownie | Broccoli |
| Orange | Banana | Kiwi | Brownie | Broccoli |  |
| Banana | Kiwi | Brownie | Broccoli |  |  |
| Kiwi | Brownie | Broccoli |  |  |  |
| Brownie | Broccoli |  |  |  |  |
| Broccoli |  |  |  |  |  |

Result would be Broccoli. If column1, row6 Broccoli wasn't there then result would be Brownie/Broccoli.

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arrowroot | Artichoke | Arugula | Asparagus | Bamboo Shoots | Beans |
| Beets | Carrots | Celery | Brownie | Broccoli |  |
| Banana | Kiwi | Carrots | Garlic |  |  |
| Chocolate chips | Bread | Cheese |  |  |  |
| Juice | Pop |  |  |  |  |
| Chips |  |  |  |  |  |

Result would be Carrots.

Comment: What do you mean by most common string? Give example of your data and the expected result.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Updated.

Comment: Copy all data into new sheet, arrange in one column, remove duplicates. use `COUNTIF` for each string in the list of unique strings against the entire matrix. get `MAX` of that column, or use conditional formatting, or sort by value, or whatever you want to do to find the most common string. If this doesn't satisfy, please edit your question to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The following would work:

```
=LET(Source,A2:F7,
     ShortList,UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<Outer><Inner>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Source),",","</Inner><Inner>")&"</Inner></Outer>","/Outer/Inner")),
     Occurrences,COUNTIF(Source,ShortList),

 TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,SORT(IF(Occurrences=MAX(Occurrences),ShortList,""))))
```

It uses `TEXTJOIN()` to put the list all together, losing blanks. Then `FILTERXML()`'s trick to turn it into HTML and break it into an array that Excel recognizes as such. `UNIQUE()` then obtains a list of single instances of each value present.

Then `COUNTIF()` is used to obtain counts for each unique item, `MAX()` obtains the highest value from the list of those counts, and the `IF()` tests each unique item's count against the max value to find qualified results. `SORT()` puts those qualified results in alphabetical order.

Finally, `TEXTJOIN()` takes the qualified results and formats them for the desired output string.

(If sorting is not desired (or not necessary), just edit that function out. I assumed it would be desirable (figuring the "Brownie/Broccoli" string was not ironclad, just a fast showing of desired result) and figured putting it in and you editing it out is clearer than not putting it in, just saying "Sort it then" and leaving that for you to work out.)

The `LET()` is organized for ease and logic. "Ease" in that the range to work on occurs at the immediate start and only there so is easy to edit. Nothing else varies in the present version so it moves on to intermediate calculation Names in a bottom up presentation (maybe better described as "from the inside outward" to describe their precedence in the formula). And finally, the resulting working formula.

Comment: Unfortunately not working. #NAME? error

Comment: @XmalevolentX This answer relies on functions that are only available in Office 365. That may well be why you get a `#NAME?` error. Can you update your post with which version you are using? (You can see this by opening the File menu and then clicking Account near the bottom left of that screen.)

Comment: @EngineerToast Version 16.48 (21041102). License is a Microsoft 365 Subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a User Defined Function, written in VBA

Entering this UDF is easy:

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF),

- `<alt-F11>` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
- Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
- Then, from the top menu, select `Insert => Module`
- paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `=mostFrequent(A1:F6)` in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Function mostFrequent(r As Range) As Variant()
    Dim arr As Variant, dict As Object
    Dim v
    Dim result(1)
    
'read range into vba array for faster processing
arr = r
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
'read into dictionary and get the count of each item
For Each v In arr
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        If Not dict.Exists(v) Then
            dict.Add Key:=v, Item:=1
        Else
            dict(v) = dict(v) + 1
        End If
    End If
Next v

'find max count
For Each v In dict.Keys
    If dict(v) > result(1) Then
        result(0) = v
        result(1) = dict(v)
    End If
Next v

'return most frequent string and it's count
mostFrequent = result
    
End Function
```

[image]

**Algorithm**

- Read the range into a VBA array for fastest processing
- Enter each string into a dictionary where

  - Key = the string
  - Value = the count of that string
- Return the string that has the highest count
- *In the code below, we actually return a 2-element array where the second element is the count of the item*

  - *You can optionally return this using, depending on your excel version, the dynamic array feature or the Index function.*